# JavaScript RegularExpression to return string between [ ]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working on a project using jQuery and JavaScript. There will be several `a` elements within the DOM, and these can be grouped using the `rel` attribute, something like `jqgal[mygal1]`.

Once one of the anchors is clicked, I want to extract the value between the squared brackets, and read it into a variable for use later in the script. So for example in the following markup:

`<a href="my_image_1.jpg" rel="jqgal[mygal1]"><img src="some_image.jpg" /></a>`

The RegularExpression should return `mygal1`. I have been trying to figure this out and so far haven't turned up much (it's been one of those days). Can anyone indicate the correct regular expression to perform this action? If it helps, the string outside of the brackets will always be `jqgal[]`.

Comment: Is it ever possible to have something like "jqgal[mygal1[something_else]]" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
$('a[rel^="jqgal"]').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("rel").match(/jqgal\[(.*)\]/)[1];
    // Do what you need with the 'val'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/^.*?\[(.*?)\]/` regex on your rel attribute. The content of the group **1** (captured by the first parenthesis group) should be what you want.

```
var data = /^.*?\[(.*?)\]$/.exec(link.rel)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "jqgal[mygal1]"
var re = /\[([^\]]+)\]/
console.log( str.match(re) );
```

Explain reg exp

```
\[       find a [ character - the \ character escapes the [ so it matches the text
(        capture group start
[^\]]+   match any character that is not a ]
)        capture group end
\]       match a closing [ (not needed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex: `/jqgal\[(.*)\]/`

It will search for any string inside `jqgal[]`.

Example:

```
"jqgal[mygal1]".match(/jqgal\[(.*)\]/)
> ["jqgal[mygal1]", "mygal1"]
```